# I'm trying to use CSS to position my Flex app but it's not working

Tags: html, css, apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to position my Flex app so that its in the bottom 40% vertically, and the left 70% horizontally. This is how I define the flash section in CSS:

```
#flashContent { display:none;position:absolute; top:60%;width:70%;height:40%;}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="flashContent">
            <p>
                To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 
                10.0.0 or greater is installed. 
            </p>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://"); 
                document.write("<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='" 
                                + pageHost + "www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get Adobe Flash player' /></a>" ); 
            </script> 


    <noscript>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="434" height="100%" id=app name>
            <param name="movie" value=link_to_the_file />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data=link_to_the_file width="434" height="100%">
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <!--[if gte IE 6]>-->
                <p> 
                    Either scripts and active content are not permitted to run or Adobe Flash Player version
                    10.0.0 or greater is not installed.
                </p>
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </noscript> 
</div>
```

But it's still just appearing in the top-left corner. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: can you provide some picture or codepen ?.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the values in percentage in flex. If you want to put your stuff in centre, then we have `horizontalAlign` and for vertically, we have `verticalAlign` properties.

Specify left, top, bottom and right in numbers only,